# How to navigate from one component to a particular division of another component in angular?

Tags: typescript, navigation, angular10

I want to navigate from one component using `router.navigate(['/divofanothercomponent'])` in angular. Given below is the code.

ts file of Component A

```
# imports
abc(){
alert('please login')
this.router.navigate(['/componentB'],{fragment:'drop1'});
}
```

html of component B

```
<section>  
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav justify-content-between">
  
        <ng-template id="drop1" #notLogged>
          <div class="group-left d-flex">
  
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
              <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownForm1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" ngbDropdownToggle>
                  <i class="fas fa fa-user"></i> Login
                </a>
                <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownForm1" class="dropdown-menu drop-adjust">
                  <form class="px-4 py-3" action="" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" role="form" [formGroup]="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="username">Username</label>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Username" aria-describedby="username"
                        placeholder="Enter Username" formControlName = "logid">
                      </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label for="password">Password</label>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" aria-describedby="email"
                        placeholder="***********" formControlName = "logpass">
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
        </ng-template>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </section>
```

I want to navigate from component A to division dropdownForm1 of Component B. How can I get to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Simpler/better answer:

OK, so after your comment I did more reading about this, and it seems that you're not the only one seeing it not working. There are at least these two issues ([1](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33240) & [2](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547)) that could prevent it from working for conditional templates (for e.g. with *ngIf), as I know you have in your project.

So let's forget about what we did in the initial answer, i.e remove all the stuff with Router configuration since it's not needed, and instead make your `ComponentB` class look like this:

```
import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';
import { AfterViewInit, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './b.component.html'
})
export class BComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.route.fragment
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(fragment => this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(fragment));
  }
}
```

This should do the trick! I have created this stackblitz angular app for testing it: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3pydk?file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts.

---

### Initial generic answer, based on Router Options:

There are a few steps needed in order to achieve this, nothing too complicated. But first of all just a small note about your html template:

Do not use `<ng-template>` like this, since the content of a ng-template is not rendered until someone references that template (for e.g. by using `*ngIf=".. ; else notLogged"`). If you do have this already in your code, then all's good.

Another thing is that when referenced, only the content of a `ng-template` gets added to the DOM, not the `<ng-template>` itself, since that's not a HTML element. Which means that if you put an `id="..."` attribute on it, it will get lost.
In this case, it means that you need to take `id="drop1"` out of the ng-template tag and move it on the div below it, i.e.:

```
<ng-template #notLogged>
  <div id="drop1" class="group-left d-flex"
```

---

Ok, now on the actual navigation. You need to follow the steps below to make it work:

a) you need to set up the angular router properly for this to work as expected (by default this type of fragment URL navigation is disabled, btw).

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
    scrollOffset: [0, 64],
  };

const routes: Routes = [
...
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes, routerOptions)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

b) now that the router configuration is right, you can do a fragment URL navigation either from a html template:

```
<a [routerLink]="'/componentB'" fragment="drop1">Go to section!</a>
```

or, as in your question, from a component's code:

```
this.router.navigate(['/componentB'], {fragment:'drop1'});
```

---

For more info, check out [this](https://www.geekstrick.com/fragment-url-in-angular-8/) article.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I already have tried it. But still I am not getting the dropdown box that I am expecting. <div id="drop1">... is a drop down in component B.

Comment: Ok, just added a new/better answer. Please check it  out :)

Comment: It is navigating to that div but still it is not opening the drop down. I am expecting that dropdown box to open... as it contains form to be field by user for login.

Comment: The title of this SO question implies the navigation to a specific section of another component. That's covered in two different approached in this answer, which as you say does the actual navigation to the element.

Opening a dropdown at navigation is a different issue that should get a different question for. At least for avoiding future confusion about what we're actually answering here.