# How to navigate into different component's section in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I would be able to navigate from homepage into contact "map" section.

I've tried use fragment but my link didn't change.

On my homepage component i have button which uses localize and translate pipes.

```html
    <app-button [outline]="true" [url]="'/contact' | localize">{{ 'CONTACT.BTN' | translate}}</app-button>
```

It has following structure:

```html
    <button
            [disabled]="disabled"
            type="submit"
            [replaceUrl]="replaceUrl"
            [skipLocationChange]="skipLocationChange"
            [routerLink]="url"
            class="btn"
            [ngClass]="{
                'btn-primary': !outline && bcgColor == 'green',
                'btn-white text-primary': bcgColor == 'white',
                'btn-outline': outline,
                disabled: disabled ? disabled : ''
            }"
        >
            <div>
                <span><ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="passedValue"></ng-container></span><span></span>
            </div>
        </button>
```

In another component "contact" i have section map where i want to navigate

```html
       <div class="row gx-0 mb-13 mb-md-14">
            <div class="col" id='map'>
                <google-map></google-map>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: try `[routerLink]="[url]"`

Comment: check over this once. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68996546/how-to-navigate-from-one-component-to-a-particular-division-of-another-component